# Хибернейт не понимает GROUP_CONCAT  (MySQL)

Tags: hibernate, java, mysql

```
Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
List<Object[]> list = session.createSQLQuery("select GROUP_CONCAT (столбец_double) FROM моя_таблица").list();
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

Запрос выполняется с ошибкой:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -4
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:79)
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:104)
at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:393)
```

Не понимает "тип", видимо. Как можно его задать?

Answer (score 1):

Правда придется разобраться что там за тип.

`registerHibernateType( Types.LONGVARBINARY, Hibernate.BLOB.getName() );`

Попробуйте создать View или TempTable с данными вашего запроса внутри, а затем узнайте, что там за тип такой через запрос `describe table_name;`

И не пробовали ли вы в запросе использовать `AS`?

Или загляните на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044244/org-hibernate-mappingexception-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-2002)

Answer (score 1):

`hiernate` просит указать диалект `db`. указать его надо в `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

к примеру

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
```